# How to leave space for hidden text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processing

I'm a teacher that uses Microsoft Word to create worksheets for my students. When I'm making notes, sometimes I like to use fill-in-the-blank. Right now, I save two versions of the document, one with blanks (underscores or underlined spaces) and another with the filled in answers. This is getting to be cumbersome because not only does each document take up 2 files worth of space, but every time I make a change to one file I must make the same exact change to the other file.

I'd like to take advantage of Word's **hidden text** feature, but it's not working the way I would like.

For those of you unaware, you can highlight some text, go to `Format > Font...` (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the Mac) and check the `Hidden` checkbox to hide text. Depending on your settings, this can be a useful feature.

I have my settings set such that I can see hidden text on screen, but it will not be printed. When the program removes hidden text from the printed document, it removes the text altogether as if it were never typed.

> A relation is a **function** iff every input in the domain has exactly one output.

For example, I'd like the word "function" to be removed from the notes and replaced with a blank so that students can fill it in themselves. When I hide the word "function" and print the document, it prints the following:

> A relation is a  iff every input in the domain has exactly one output.

What I'd like it to print is the following:

> A relation is a __________________ iff every input in the domain has exactly one output.

How can I get word to leave a placeholder for hidden text? Is there a way to leave the underline there as shown above?

I don't like the idea of using the Comments and/or Markup feature, so please no suggestions regarding that.

Comment: I suggest you look at *Conditional text* in Word instead of your hidden text approach. E.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpIW9GoZXMo. Based on a condition you either print the answer or the underscores. Set the condition at the beginning of your document.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by soandos was a good start for me. However, when replacing text of variable length, it's not very convenient to use a fixed number of underscore characters.
My fix:

- use the same formatting options as suggested by soandos
  then
- in the "find what" box, use the following code "^?"
- in the "replace with" box, just type "_" (one underscore character or any other suitable replacement)

What the above will do is substitute each hidden character with an underscore character (or other replacement character(s)). This solved the problem of words of varying length for me.

Answer (score 2):

What you are going to want to do is before printing, do a find and replace by the hidden attribute to ______, and then print (but don't save) that copy.

To search by the hidden attribute, go to find and replace, and then with the focus on find, click the Format->Font button.

In that dialog box, select the hidden box, and not every other box.

The result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this replace everything?

Comment: @Louis this replaces all hidden text (one group at a time) with _____. The rest of the document is unchanged. Simply don't save it after this

Comment: You could make a macro that does this, prints, and reverts. And I believe you just need to check the Hidden box while leaving all others indeterminate, otherwise you wouldn't replace hidden text in small caps, e.g.

Comment: @Joey I could, but it sounds like overkill. Additionally, that means that the document needs to be trusted, will be harder to send to colleagues, etc. Its not needed at this point. Additionally, a simple undo is the revert, so that can easily be done manually as well

Comment: @soandos Taking the first argument for example, it's saying replace everything that's not strikethrough.

Comment: @Louis you misunderstand. It is saying if the text !strikethrough&&not small caps && not all caps ... Its not OR its AND. Feel free to try it out

Comment: @soandos ahh, I see now. I'm Installing Word now actually.

Comment: This seems like a good approach but how would I go about replacing different strings with different lengths? Some fill-in-the-blanks are longer than others and it wouldn't make sense to replace all the blanks with the same length underscore.

Comment: @TestSubject528491: Might need to write a VBA macro then to find each hidden word, count the number of chars in it and replace with those many underscores.

Comment: years later… I wonder if there's a way to replace the text with itself, but formatted such that the color is white? That way I needn’t worry about the number of characters. however that wouldn’t address the problem of providing the underline. even if the color of the text is white then so would be the underline… I guess one could manually draw them in after printing

Comment: Yes, this is possible, just use replace with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the text each time, I found a slightly better way:

Put each of your answers inside a text box. It has to follow these conditions :

- Borderless
- Without margins or padding
- Anchored to the text
- Put in the text box the hidden text
- [Add the fill-in-here line with this tip](https://superuser.com/questions/562396/micrososft-word-creating-a-textbox-with-only-top-border)

The text inside the text box can then be hidden, but the text box will stay there, taking space with its fixed with.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

1. Create a style with style type Character for the text that should not print.
2. Assign a colour to the text to stand out.
3. Prior to printing update the Style to have text colour white.

This should update all occurrences. (If not you can use Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S and then right click on your style to select all)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I have an exam with 2 versions required. When I print without hidden text, all the spaces and formatting disappears, so I just get a list of questions without spaces for answers. The only way I can find, without coding or macros etc, is to add text boxes for the answers with the hidden text within.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the author's question consider editing it so it does